# Unable to use -h with a file tcsh

Tags: unix, symlink, tcsh

I'm unable to use -h test flag for a file to find whether it is a symlink in tcsh.

Here is my code snippet and the error.

```
#!/bin/tcsh
foreach i (`ls`)
    if ( -h "$i" ) then
        echo $i
    endif
end
```

**Error:** if: Badly formed number.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Don't use tcsh to write script shells, better use standard POSIX shell or bash.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/tcsh

foreach i (*)
  if ( -l "$i") then
    echo "$i"
  endif
end
```

First: the `*` is better than `ls`. Second: your desired test is `-l` and not `-h`. The `tcsh`'s test doesn't same as the `/bin/test` (or `[...]`). Check the [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcsh(1)), (sub)section *File inquiry operators*.